# Web Scraping with Beautifulsoup: Cannot find class

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to python and trying some webscraping with beautifulsoup. After following some youtube videos and endlessly looking for answers on stackflow, I decided I would post for help.

With the below code I am hoping to extract data from the website. I've noticed that one 3 div are listed when I print(len(div)), but there are several div's on the webpage. Other posts point to soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'responsive-text-label'}) as a solution, however, when I print() that code (and others similar), I get [] as a result from pyCharm.

`enter code here`
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
    from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq

```
my_url = 'https://coronavirus.jhu.edu/map.html'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')
total_cases = page_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'responsive-text-label'})

print(total_cases)

RESULTS FROM PYCHARM
[]
```

Thank you in advance for taking the time and helping me out.

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class

Comment: The page data is loaded using java script.  you will not be able to scrape it just by BS. you will need to use solutions based on selenium.

Comment: What all data do you need?